# Monitor ActiveRecord records and find patterns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, microservices

Well, I'll try to be as clear as possible in my problem, and I hope to get answers with Ruby because I'm currently studying Ruby on Rails, but of course other solutions and services are welcome if they solve the problem.

Assuming I have a **Colors** model, with its **name**, **number** attributes .

The colors that the model will receive will be limited to BLUE, GREEN and PINK only, and its 30 numbers: EX: 10 blue, 10 green and 10 pink.

So considering that my model colors will just register:

```
[{name: "blue", number: "3"}, {name: "blue", number: "4"}, {name: "green", number: "12"}] ...
```

The problem lies in how I can't figure out where to start looking for predefined patterns and having a response once the pattern is correct. For example:

Assume I have a list with the pattern: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]

Every time my model receives a new color, starting from the last one that came out and its previous ones formed the same pattern as above, I would get a type of return.

I just can't imagine where to start. I thought of a simple method like this being executed on a callback of every new record. But where should I implement this? where the list of colors will be persistent for adding new colors and getting to be the same as the proposed standard?

```
pattern = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]
  last_record = Color.first
  def monitor_pattern(last_record, pattern)
        
    color_list = []
    color_list.push(last_record.name)

    if color_list == pattern
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

I don't know if I can be clear, but I appreciate any kind of help!

## EDIT

Hello friends, thanks for the answer... Well here we go, here is my application https://historicosblaze.com/doubles

Now let's see if I can explain, if you notice in the application, a new color is being registered every few seconds, these colors are being registered in the bank.

If you look, colors can create patterns, like, 3 reds in a row, 7 blacks in a row, 1 red 1 black 1 red 1 black... and so on, presuming I have pre-established patterns and want to keep monitoring the arrivals of new records, I can't imagine where and with what I should monitor the creation of these patterns, if for example, in the last output of 1 red followed by 7 reds, it formed a pattern of 8 reds in a row, which was a pre-established pattern , 8 red, this must be being monitored and recorded somewhere.

[Um diagrama bem bruto mas pode ajudar!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZOpl2qS2z2xuncoAqkNidlaa-POijKVP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "The problem lies in how I can't figure out where to start looking for predefined patterns and having a response once the pattern is correct" I think you need to explain exactly what you want to happen better, I can't understand from your question what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can you describe what your ultimate goal is for this code? It's not clear yet what you're trying to do. What input are you expecting, and for that input, what output are you expecting? That might be a good place to start...

Comment: Hello friends, thanks for the answer... Well here we go, here is my application https://historicosblaze.com/doubles and I put a few more words above

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understood your requirements correctly but it feels like this might be what you are looking for:

```
def monitor_pattern(pattern)
  last_four_colors = Color.last(4)

  pattern == last_four_colors.map(&:name)
end
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the answer, but the method itself is not my problem, but where would this method be applied? As a service it would be active with pre-established standards and monitoring each bank output to form the standards.

Comment: That depends on why you want to monitor for patterns and what to do if there is such a pattern. A after commit callback might work or a background job.